# Spring Config Server reloading native properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Are native properties supposed to be reloading dynamically? E.g. if I have:

```
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=classpath:/config-native
```

And a file called sample.properties with:

```
example-property="Hello from config server"
```

And then I change example-property value to something else, and do another GET against Config Server without restarting it, I'm still seeing the old value displayed.

Is this expected behavior? I'm able to see updated property value if I do the same with non-native (git) setup.

Comment: I have a suspicion it has to do with `classpath:/`. If it were `file:/` it would always work. With classpath, things might get cached with a classloader.

Comment: Hi Spencer, yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion it has to do with `classpath:/`. If it were `file:/` it would always work. With classpath, things might get cached with a classloader.